# facebook like popover example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make facebook style user information when you hover over the user picture showing popover. but the user information in the empty area below the picture opens. I simply point the mouse on the user's photo and name want to open the popover.

My [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GN2G4/) example

This is my **CSS** kod :

```
#hover {
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width:50px;
    float:left;
    left: 50px;
    top: 25px;
    height:0px;
}
#hover:hover {
    width:180px;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
}
#popup {
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow:2px 3px 6px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px #888;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px #888;
    z-index: 999999;
    width:369px;
}
#hover:hover #popup {
    opacity: 1;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
.popup-arrow-border {
    border-color: transparent transparent #2c3a6b transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:-8%;
    left:15px;
}
.popup-arrow {
    border-color: transparent transparent #2c3a6b transparent;
    background-color:transparent transparent #2c3a6b transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:-8%;
    left:15px;
}
.user-logo {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
}
.user-name {
    left:70px;
    position: absolute;
    font-weight:bolder;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.text {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:black;
    font-size:1.2em;
}
```

And also **HTML** code:

```
<div class="text">Hover your mouse over the image or text below</div>
<div id="hover">
    <div class="user-logo"> <a href="#"><img src="https://scontent-a-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/t1/1959595_793389784022662_686223499_n.jpg" alt="facebook user icon" width="50px" height="50px" /></a>

    </div>
    <div class="user-name"> <a href="#">Techglimpse.com</a>

    </div>
    <div id="popup">
        <img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1/1497719_793389800689327_525238023_n.jpg" />
        <div class="popup-arrow-border"></div>
        <div class="popup-arrow"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`opacity: 0` means the image is displayed, but is invisible - the image is still there! Since, it is a part of the `#hover` div, hovering over image will make itself non opaque again!

So, use `display: none` instead of `opacity: 0` and `display: block` instead of `opacity: 1`.

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GN2G4/1/). I have added borders to everything to help you visualize it better.

Comment: You wrote're right. Thank you for your answer. However, there is a problem in hover. Follow the drop-down arrow in the popover just with the mouse does not disappear.